# How to remove the quotation mark in formula object?

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
formula <-  Y ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G
pryr::substitute_q(formula, list(Y = as.name('Ya + Yb')))
# `Ya + Yb` ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G
```

what I am hoping for is:

```
Ya + Yb ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G
```

I have tried `noquote()`, `as.symbol()`, `as.name()` so on so on, but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pryr::substitute_q(formula, list(Y = quote(Ya + Yb)))
# Ya + Yb ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not using `update` from base?

```
update(formula, Ya + Yb ~ .)
# Ya + Yb ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G
```

or

```
x <- "Ya + Yb"
update(formula, paste(x, "~ ."))
# Ya + Yb ~ A + B + C + D + E + F + G
```